# Something strange with BoundingBox in XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I have strange problem with BoundingBox and things that in make.
For loop wont work correctly and cause problem that dont change variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < thing.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < thing.Length; j++)
            {
                if (thing[i].bb.Intersects(thing[j].bb) && i != j)
                {
                    thing[i].spriteSpeed *= -1;
                    thing[j].spriteSpeed *= -1;
                    soundEffect.Play(0.2f, -1f, 0f);
                }
            }
        }
```

But if i change j variable to static number, like zero, code will work fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < thing.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < thing.Length; j++)
            {
                if (thing[i].bb.Intersects(thing[0].bb) && i != 0)
                {
                    thing[i].spriteSpeed *= -1;
                    thing[0].spriteSpeed *= -1;
                    soundEffect.Play(0.2f, -1f, 0f);
                }
            }
        }
```

P.S. Thing is a struct that looks like:

```
struct Thing
    {
        public Texture2D myTexture;
        public Vector2 spritePosition;
        public Vector2 spriteSpeed;
        public BoundingBox bb;
        public Vector3 start, end;
    }
```

Comment: Tnx Corey. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are updating both objects both times.

Consider the case where you have two items in the list and their bounding boxen are overlapping.  Passing through your loop you get:

```
i == 0, j == 0: Skip because (i == j)
i == 0, j == 1: Reverse direction of [0] and [1]
i == 1, j == 0: Reverse direction of [1] and [0]
i == 1, j == 1: Skip because (i == j)
```

Working through the sequence you have reversed the items twice, returning them to their original headings.

To prevent this, and incidentally reduce the number of tests required to process the full list of objects, the `j` variable should always start 1 higher than `i`, since all comparisons for `i <= j` are either already done or are invalid.

Try this code instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < thing.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < thing.Length; j++)
    {
        if (thing[i].bb.Intersects(thing[j].bb))
        {
            thing[i].spriteSpeed *= -1;
            thing[j].spriteSpeed *= -1;
            soundEffect.Play(0.2f, -1f, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

This has the effect of reducing the number of comparisons by about half (actually `(n^2-n)/2` if we're being precise) as well as removing all of the double reversals.  Each possible combination of items in the list is tested only once.